# TemplateSyntaxError caught DoesNotExist while iterating through a forloop on a populated list of forms

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have been following this useful-looking article http://collingrady.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/editing-multiple-objects-in-django-with-newforms/. Unfortunately he doesn't hint at the template code, so I'm guessing there.

I want to create a bunch of forms in a page, to add multiple objects to a model, with some common properties set by another form either in the page's variables or at the top of the page. This is for a teacher's marksheet.

My views.py:

```
def record_assessments(request, teachinggroup, objective):
    theclass = TeachingGroup.objects.get(name__iexact = teachinggroup)
    pupils = Pupil.objects.filter(teaching_group = theclass)
    theobjective = Objective.objects.get(code = objective)
    thedate = datetime.date.today()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        aforms = [PupilAssessmentForm(request.POST, prefix=x.id, instance=Assessment()) for x in pupils]
        if all(af.is_valid() for af in aforms):
            for af in aforms:
                new_record = af.save(commit = False)
                new_record.objective = theobjective
                new_record.date = thedate
                new_record.save()
            return redirect("/app/" + theclass + "/" + marksheet + "/" + theobjective.strand.code|lower + "/")
    else:
        aforms = [PupilAssessmentForm(prefix=str(x.id)) for x in pupils]
    return render_to_response('recordassessments.html', locals())
```

I haven't managed to check the logic in the first if loop yet, as I haven't managed to POST the form properly yet.

The page renders properly if I put

```
    else:
        aforms = [PupilAssessmentForm(prefix=str(x.id), instance=x) for x in pupils]
```

But then I'm tying a ModelForm from the Assessment model to an object in the Pupil model, which seems wrong.

My template:

```
{% for af in aforms %}
<form action="" method="post">
{{af.instance}}{{ af.errors }}
<p>
{{ af }}
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The error (selected snippets):

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    Caught DoesNotExist while rendering:

error at line 20
Caught DoesNotExist while rendering: 
20    {% for af in aforms %}
```

And yet the aforms list appears in the page variables:

```
aforms  
[<two.app.forms.PupilAssessmentForm object at 0x21db0d0>,
 <two.app.forms.PupilAssessmentForm object at 0x21db650>]
```

Comment: That's a very old article, probably written before [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) were available. You should be using those.

Comment: Thanks, I've played around, but I don't think formsets can do what I want. Unless I'm extremely stupid, which is possible. I want to iterate over the pupils, getting previous assessment data for each to display in the adjacent table cell, and then render a single form field which will add a record for that pupil, or update one if it exists. Formsets seem to me to be for entirely new objects (straight formsets) or for iterating over the objects in the model you're updating (modelformsets). Is it possible to iterate over one model (Pupil) but add/update records in another (Assessment)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but I managed to do it by changing the list to a dictionary, which suited my needs anyway for displaying the form as a table row per pupil together with some other assessment data. My original question remains open for anyone who knows an alternative method that more directly addresses the question I was originally asking, but here's how I did it:

views.py (the relevant bits):

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        assessment_grid = {}
        for x in pupils:
            form = PupilAssessmentForm(request.POST, prefix=str(x.id))
            try:
                assessment = Assessment.objects.filter(objective = theobjective).filter(pupil = x).filter(date__lte = thedate).latest('date')
            except Assessment.DoesNotExist:
                assessment = None
            pupil_row = [assessment, form]
            assessment_grid[x] = pupil_row
        if all(pupil_row[1].is_valid() for pupil, pupil_row in assessment_grid.items()):
            for pupil, pupil_row in assessment_grid.items():
                new_record = pupil_row[1].save(commit = False)
                new_record.objective = theobjective
                new_record.date = thedate
                new_record.teacher = theclass.teacher
                new_record.pupil = pupil
                new_record.save()
            return redirect("some link")
     else:
        assessment_grid = {}
        for x in pupils:
            form = PupilAssessmentForm(prefix=str(x.id))
            try:
                assessment = Assessment.objects.filter(objective = theobjective).filter(pupil = x).filter(date__lte = thedate).latest('date')
            except Assessment.DoesNotExist:
                assessment = None
            pupil_row = [assessment, form]
            assessment_grid[x] = pupil_row
    return render_to_response('recordassessments.html', locals())
```

I'm not sure whether there's a more elegant way to assemble the dictionary, as mine isn't particularly DRY. And I have no idea why I could unpack a dictionary containing a form yet not a list. Was my syntax wrong? Anyway: problem sorted; page renders.

Answer (score 0):

Odd, django isn't supposed to throw DoesNotExist while rendering django models... but.... you are rendering a form. My suggestion would be to do some checking for results in your view code to make sure you are getting results in pupils and your other querysets.